# How to use multiple parameters in where clause?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to make a filter with different parameters. One of parameter is $article_title. But it can be empty . My problem is even if its not empty i get null in `return $comments`. That is because this part of code:

```
 $q->where('language_id', $default_language_id)->where('title','like',$article_title);
```

This is my function

```
public function getResultCommentsWithArticle($comment,$user_firstname,$article_title,$orderBy){
      $default_language = Languages::where('default',1)->first();
      $default_language_id = $default_language->id;

      $comments = ArticleComments::orderBy($orderBy,'desc')
          ->with(['user', 'article', 'article.translations' => function($q) use($default_language_id,$article_title) {
              $q->where('language_id', $default_language_id)->where('title','like',$article_title);
          }])->paginate(10);
      return $comments;
    }
```

EDIT:

I also tried like this:

```
$comments = ArticleComments::orderBy($orderBy,'desc')
            ->with(['user', 'article', 'article.translations' => function($q) use($default_language_id,$article_title) {

                $q->where([
                    ['language_id', '=', $default_language_id],
                    ['title', 'like', '%'. $article_title .'%'],
                ]);
            }])->paginate(10);
```

But i get all comments and not `comments` with `title="something"`

Comment: Could you explain your exact question? Right now I could implement a number generator and it would be a valid answer :)

Comment: problem is that i always get null when i use ->where('title','like',$article_title); even if i have that title in database

Comment: is it clear at all right now? :D

Comment: Can you post the result of the dumped `$comments` var? If you have comments in your database this query shouldn't return empty array (no matter what you pass in $default_language).

Comment: Sorry, I misread your post! I seem to remember you couldn't simple paginate (the `->paginate(10)`) the result of an orderBy query, but I can't find any support on that. Can you do a `->get()` and see what that does?

Comment: Are you saying you want an OR condition in the where clause (where language_id = default_language_id OR title like article_title)? If yes use orWhere

Comment: when i use ->get() and dumped $comments i get all comments

Comment: it not filter anything at all even if i enter something for $article_title

Comment: It's really not clear what you want. The query you posted filters _only_ the article translations. It will select **all** comments with **all** of the comment's articles with **filtered** translations. Judging by your latest edit you actually want to filter the comments. Is that correct?

Comment: Is title present as a field in any of the other 3 tables: user, articles, translations?

Comment: I want all comments with all articles where article translation have title = ....

Comment: it is in translations

Comment: Sorry I meant is there a title field in comments, user or articles?

Comment: So you want to select **all** comments with **filtered** articles (by the translation title)? You'll need to use `->whereHas()`. Let me know if that's what you want (all comments, with filtered articles) and I'll show you an example.

Comment: no...i have title in article.translations

Comment: try `'translations.title'` instead of `'title'` if translations is the name of the table

Comment: Oh if you only want comments whose articles translations match the title, then use whereHas()

Comment: @devk yes thats i want, by translation title and where languge_id = 1, that is also in translation

Comment: @Paras i tried that im getting an error that is no column in database with that name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$comments = ArticleComments::orderBy($orderBy,'desc')
            ->with(['user', 'article'])
            ->whereHas('article.translations', function($q) 
                use($default_language_id,$article_title) {

                $q->where('language_id', $default_language_id)
                ->where('title','like',$article_title);
            })->paginate(10);
```

Comment: I have modified my answer

Comment: The problem is that `->whereHas` takes 2 arguments. You need to remove the `=>` in it and replace it with a comma. That's why Paras is getting an error.

Comment: Thanks @devk I will modify my answer!

Comment: Modified, please check now if it works the way you want @None

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$comments =  ArticleComments::orderBy($orderBy, 'desc')
    ->with(['user', 'article' => function ($q) use($default_language_id, $article_title) {
        $q->with('translations')
            ->whereHas('translations', function ($q) use($default_language_id, $article_title) {
                $q->where('language_id', $default_language_id)->where('title','like',$article_title);
            });
    }])->paginate();
```

This will select **all** comments and it will attach to it articles **that match** the translation.title and default language id.

In case you want to filter the comments instead of articles you would do this:

```
$comments =  ArticleComments::orderBy($orderBy, 'desc')
    ->with(['user', 'article.translation'])
    ->whereHas('article', function ($q) use($default_language_id, $article_title) {
        $q->whereHas('translations', function ($q) use($default_language_id, $article_title) {
                $q->where('language_id', $default_language_id)->where('title','like',$article_title);
            });
    })->paginate();

    return $comments;
```

Comment: i tried this but again i get all comments, for all articles, and not what i enter in $article_title

Comment: Try second one. I wrote that the first one gets **all** comments. The 2nd one filters the comments. I'm sorry but it really really isn't clear what you want, that's why I wrote both. Edit: also can you put php tag in your post so that the code gets properly highlighted (it's far more readable that way).

Comment: I think problem with your 2nd solution is that it loads users and translations, whereas OP wants users and articles but only wants the check on translations

Comment: Maybe yeah. I just assumed he needs the translations as well (since he's including them in `->with()` in the question). If he does it's a really bad idea to lazy load them (n+1 and all that). But I guess he got it to work as intended :)